# "Maximum update depth exceeded" only on remote server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

When I build and deploy my project on our NGINX server and then call the app I get the following error:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:198 Error: Minified React error #185; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=185 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
    at react-dom.production.min.js:13
    at c (react-dom.production.min.js:14)
    at nc (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.production.min.js:130)
    at e.y.setState (react.production.min.js:13)
    at react-router.js:63
    at t (history.js:155)
    at history.js:173
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.notifyListeners (history.js:172)
```

The link in the error shows me the following explanation:

> We highly recommend using the development build locally when debugging
>   your app since it tracks additional debug info and provides helpful
>   warnings about potential problems in your apps, but if you encounter
>   an exception while using the production build, this page will
>   reassemble the original text of the error.

And the error...

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

When I develop locally, I call the `npm run-script dev` which does the following:

`webpack-dev-server --open --mode development`

In my `Jenkins` job, I do this to build and deploy the application:

```
npm install --verbose
npm run-script build
```

Build is doing this: `webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --mode production`

**Now to my problem:**

The mentioned error leads to a white page and is *not* repeatable in my local environment. The error just occurs on the deployed app on the NGINX server.

I really don't know how to solve this issue that only occurs on the server and does not show any hints what the cause of this problem might be, but only tells me to fix this issue locally where the problem is not even present.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do to find out the cause of this, or even know the reason for the bug itself?

Comment: Do you have a large input of data or somewhere you call setState multiple times? 
By default react has a lot of memory assigned and won't fail. 
What might be happening is, on the nginx server, the react app is not assigned a lot of memory, so a heavy api call might lead to this since it runs out of memory. Just a thought, based on the limited info we have